# c++ vector constructor instantiation conflicts

Tags: c++, templates, vector, overload-resolution

I'm trying to implement vector container refering to 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/. There are two constructors causing some problems:

```
template <typename T>
vector (size_type n, const T& val);

template <typename T>
template <typename InputIterator>
vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

When I use `vector<int> vec(100, 1);`. It seems that both template constructor make instantiations. So I got `template <typename T> vector (size_type n, const T& val)` with **T=int** and `template <typename T> template <typename InputIterator> vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last)` with **T=int, InputIterator=int**.

How do I solve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "both template constructor make instantiations"?

Comment: Also how do you see that there's a conflict? What error message do you get? Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the standard (since C++11) requires that the overloaded [constructor of `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) taking iterator as parameter only participates in overload resolution when the arguments passed act as iterator.

> This overload only participates in overload resolution if InputIt satisfies [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator), to avoid ambiguity with the overload (2).

You can use [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) with [std::iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) to accomplish it for your own implementation of vector. e.g.

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>
vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last) { ... }
```

For the case of `InputIterator = int`, `std::iterator_traits<int>` doesn't contain any member types like `value_type`, then the overload will be ruled out of overload resolution.

---

BTW: More precisely, the problem is not "both template constructor make instantiations"; I'm not sure what's the exact type of `size_type` in your implementation, if it's some type other that `int`, like `std::size_t`, then for `vector<int> vec(100, 1);` the 1st overload won't be selected because it requires to convert the 1st argument from `int` to `std::size_t`, then the 2nd overload will be selected because it could produce a perfect match instantiation with `InputIterator = int`. That's not the behavior we expect.

Comment: ... and the standard before C++11 required that `vector(InputIter, InputIter)` acts like the other overload if the arguments are of integral type.